# Binance API in python APIError(code=-1121): Invalid symbol

Tags: python-3.x, binance-api-client

I am trying to code a binance Buy function. However the code

```
from binance.enums import *
order = client.create_order(symbol='DOGEUSDT', side = 'BUY',  type = 'MARKET', quantity = 475, timeInForce='GTC')
```

this code outputs > APIError(code=-1121): Invalid symbol.

Also, for the same symbol,

```
print(client.get_symbol_info(symbol="DOGEUSDT"))
```

ouptuts > None

The symbol DOGEUSDT exists is the orderbook. https://api.binance.com/api/v3/ticker/bookTicker
I dont know why the same symbol I get from binance is invalid.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you using the testnet? I had the same error, however when I removed testnet=True from the client initialization the error was resolved.

Answer (score 1):

two things can happen

1. client.API_URL = https://testnet.binance.vision/api

in that case change it to

https://api.binance.com/api

2. Client(api_key, secret_key, testnet=True)

in that case change testnet=False or delete it